# Is there an Unrar for Adobe AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, rar

I'm working on a file system app and I need to be able to expand rar files. Is there a way I can do that?

**UPDATE**
Should have clarified. My target platform is mobile

Answer (score 4):

You could utilize the [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) class and run the [UnRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) command line tool.

If you need a native unrar implementation then it could become it "little bit" more work. But you could try if [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) can help you in converting the UnRAR C++ source code into ActionScript.